# execute ajax when a variable contains data

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a session variable `email=$_GET['email'];` , i want to execute a ajax function when this varaible is available and do no action when the variable is not available.

How to call a ajax function when the variable is available?

Comment: i tried with button using click function but dont know what to do when function is available

Comment: post your code. You really did not thiink someone would sit down and write the whole thing for you. Did you?

Comment: yes @Akintunde i did that mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['email']) && $_GET['email'] !='') {?>
    <script>
        // your ajax function comes here
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: you don't need to check it twice with `isset()` and `!= ''`, use `!empty($_GET['email'])` instead

Comment: @Mohammad Yes You are right we can use both option.

Answer (score 0):

you can you Php code under javascript.

var emial = '';
 $.ajax({

     // your ajax code
   });